# How to make a lightbox with flexible content (headline, image and description) with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I've created a web app based on Bootstrap and I try to add a lightbox to it. I've looked for various plugins, but none will meet my requirements unfortunately.

My lightbox has two main sections that fight me really hard: an image on the top and a text with a headline and a description on the bottom.

The problem that I'm facing is, I want the lightbox restrict the size of the content, means, if the whole content is bigger then 100% vh or vw it should scale it down. And because that is hard to do with text, the image needs to be scaled. But whatever I do, I can not make the image scalable.

This is what I have so far:

HTML

```
<div id="agp-lightbox" class="agp-lightbox" @click="$emit('close')">
  <div class="lightbox-content" :key="this.index">

    <div class="content-left">
      <a class="prev" @click.stop="prev" v-show="hasPrev()"><span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="content-middle">

      <div class="close cursor fa fa-window-close" @click="$emit('close')"></div>
      <div class="numbertext">{{this.index+1}}/{{this.amount}}</div>

      <div class="img-box">
        <img v-bind:src="this.imglink">
      </div>

      <div class="caption-container">
        <h3>{{this.info.title}}</h3>
        <span v-html="this.info.description_de"></span>
        <p>
          Material: {{this.info.material_de}},
          Preis: {{this.info.price}},
          Format: {{this.info.artwork_format}}
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="content-right">
      <a class="next" @click.stop="next" v-show="hasNext()"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.agp-lightbox {
        position: fixed;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        z-index: 99;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        min-width: 0;
        min-height: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    }

    .lightbox-content {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        padding: 20px;
        height: 90%;
        width: 90%;
        min-width: 0;
        min-height: 0;
        border: solid 1px red;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .content-left {
        color: white;
        border: solid 1px green;
    }

    .content-middle {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-width: 0;
        min-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: solid 1px lightskyblue;
    }

    .content-right {
        color: white;
        border: solid 1px yellow;
    }

    .caption-container {
        color: white;
    }

    .img-box {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        min-width: 0;
        min-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        border: solid 1px orange;
    }

    .img-box img {
        display: flex;
    }

    .close, .number-text {
        display: none;
    }
```

As said, it works in general, but as soon the image gets to big, it will not shrink so the whole content will not fit and gets cut (.lightbox-content). It gets even tougher when the image is not in landscape, but portrait format...

Also here is a JS Fiddle for the example...

https://jsfiddle.net/qg52jh6a/

As a last resort, I could restrict the image size, but I want it as flexible as possible. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say you want to restrict the image size, do you want it to behave like `background-size: cover` or `background-size: contain`?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the image as a background-image and set its attributes via css instead of loading it as an image.

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your markup considerably because there is a lot of unnecessary bits in there. All you need is to use CSS flexbox in the lightbox, and then use `object-fit: contain` for your image. If you wish the image to be cropped so that it covers all area, then use `object-fit: cover`.

[Object fit is actually very widely supported today](https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit), with the notable exception of IE11 of course.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.lightbox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.lightbox__caption {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.lightbox__image {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.lightbox__image img {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="lightbox">
  <div class="lightbox__image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/800/600">
  </div>
  <div class="lightbox__caption">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately your answer is a little bit too simplyfied... Yes, your example works, but it doesn't help much, because I have to do some styling and also removing all other elements I need for a functional lightbox doesn't help much. I'll play around with object-fit a little and maybe find a good solution. Thanks